# Html and css website not being crawled properly

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a website I made with html and css. It has quite a few different pages. I published this site and it got added to google. When you search omicrome in google the main page comes up (index.html) unfortunately that's the only page that comes up in google. I don't know if I have to add something to the code. Also when I am on the website and I click on a button that brings me to a different page of my site it still says omicrome.com/ on the url it should say omicrome.com/about Why doesn't it do that? Do I have to add something to the code? I am using GoDaddy and google drive for my domain and hosting.
EDIT: Here is the code for the index.html page so you can see how I have coded it:

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <title>Omicrome</title>

     <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="img/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
     <link rel="ICON" href="img/icon.ico" type="image/ico" />

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960_24_col.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

     <meta name="Description" CONTENT="Omicrome is the place to be for       technology, science, space, gaming and internet news with the odd side of comedy. New content daily.">


  </head>
   <body>

  <div class = "container_24">
  <header>
<h1>Omicrome</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="# " class = selected>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.html">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="software.html">Software</a ></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class = "banner grid_18" href="about.html">
     <a href="elonmusk.html"  class="button" id ="new">View Article</a>

        <h2>

        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class=" grid_8 callout"></div>
     <a href="software.html"  class="button" id ="spacesoft">View Software</a>
  </header>




  <div class = "main clearfix">
  <div class ="grid_9">
      <h3>About The Site</h3>
     <p>Omicrome is where you get all your amazing content. Between tech, space, films and internet news, we've got it all here on Omicrome. We also post software and other downloadable projects on the site for you to use and enjoy. Check back daily for new interesting content or go to the articles section to see all of our content in one place. 


    <p><a href="about.html"  class="button">Find Out More</a></p>
   </div>

   <div class ="grid_9">
    <h3>Our Content</h3>
        <p>Every day we post about different things. Sometimes   we post about space, technology, films, games and the internet but you can also find news on events, the internet and even see what we're up to! Make sure to check back daily!
    </p><p>
    </p><p>  </p>
    <br>

 <p><a href="about.html" class="button">Find Out More</a></p>
</div>
    </div>
    <footer><p><strong>Omicrome</strong><a href="#"></a></p></footer>

     </div>

     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about SEO are off topic on SO and belong on webmasters.stackexchange.com and questions about server configuration belong on serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is going to Index is because that is how the Internet work. It looks for index and if it exists, it goes there. That is normal.

For the URL not changing, you need desperate files name different names. For example, if you have home.html, and you redirect there, it should be 'omicrome.com/home.html'

Check that your files are named and you are properly redirecting!

Comment: I edited the answer to show an example of my code. What do you mean by properly named and redirecting. I am using googledrive for hosting. each file has a long url and in godaddy I set omicrome.com to forward with masking to my googledrive index.html file